# PHP: Passing variable with cookie

Tags: php, variables, cookies

What's the correct way of passing variable using PHP cookie. I can't seem to get it to work? I keep getting "FAILED!"

Here's my code:

On 1st page:

```
$crpid['ONE']="PAGE1";
$crpid['TWO']="PAGE2";
$crpid['THREE']="PAGE3";

$crp_id = $_SERVER["REDIRECT_URIPART"];
$crp_value = $crpid[$crp_id];

session_start();
setcookie('crpid', $crp_value, time()+3600, "/");
```

On 2nd page:

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['crpid']) && $_COOKIE['crpid']==''){
    echo "FAILED!";
}
else{
    echo "Cookie ".$_COOKIE['crpid']." is set!";
}
```

Comment: Why not just use sessions?

Comment: The Code works fine for me!

Comment: Have you verified that $crp_value is actually assigned a value?

Otherwise, you can check if setcookie() is run successfully as it returns a bool.

Comment: It appears that it doesn't take(parse) the array value. If I change the $crp_value value to a text string, it works just fine.

Comment: The array parsing looks good to me. Maybe $_SERVER["REDIRECT_URIPART"] doesn't return what you expect?

Comment: @balpeter It does. I can echo $crp_value on the 1st page just fine. It returns correct value. I was wondering if it has something to do with the PHP version I use. I got PHP 5.4.28.